# Когда в mongodb нужно создавать новые коллекции?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Возник вопрос. Когда в mongodb нужно создавать новые коллекции? Например можно же хранить всё в колекции user имея структуру

```
user {
 field...
 field...
 posts: [{
  field...
  field...
  comments: [{
   comment, comment, comment
  }]
 }]
}
```

Но можно и разделить эту структуру на коллекции Users и Posts в Posts добавить id пользователя которому принадлежит этот пост. Можно пойти дальше и сделать тоже самое с комментариями где будет id поста и id пользователя который его добавил. Но тут попахивает реляционными базами.

Хочу понять какой подход лучше в случае mongodb.